# listening for incoming TCP connections

Tags: tcp, openshift

it seems that all the PAAS providers, including openshift, are of the

the service terminates http/https traffic, looks at the Host: header, an then forwards the request to a single listening port on your app.

i have the misfortune of having an applications that needs both an incoming http listener and a raw TCP listener.

the proxies used by the PAAS services seem to support UPGRADE only for websockets (if that).

does anyone have any "clever" work-arounds that i might use to deploy an app that needs to listen on two ports, one of which isn't HTTP? or does anyone have a "real clever" work around that lets me get the same effect with a single listening port?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of OpenShift Online, here's an FAQ that explains the current port restrictions and some workarounds:  https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port

OpenShift Online is also working on enabling cartridge authors to open their own ports as per:  https://www.openshift.com/content/at-least-one-port-for-external-use-excluding-8080-please

Let us know how it goes!  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift

Comment: many thanks. follow-up question: i can make everything work if the openshift proxy supports HTTP's CONNECT method transparently, e.g., 

  CONNECT ... HTTP/1.1

  Host: example.openshift.com

passing the CONNECT to the application and then transparently copying octets over the connection until it closes, e.g.,

    socket1.pipe(socket2); socket2.pipe(socket1);

Comment: Both links are broken unfortunatelly